# React Native/android/play store: how does updating an app work?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I'm a building a React Native app for iOS and Android. Currently, I have a internal test running through the Google Play Console for Android. The problem is, when I make a new release for my beta testers, the testers have to delete the current release from their phone and reinstall the app to see the updates. When the app is installed and I open the page in the play store, I do not see a button like 'update' or whatsoever.

How does updating an android app work? Or is this just because I'm doing internal tests?

Comment: Did you bump the version number ?

Comment: I changed the version code in my /Android/app/build.gradle if that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes I mean the versionCode and the code you can define in the play console.

Answer (score 0):

try this from GitHub:

```
react-native-version-check
```

This one seems to help you check, at least IOS and Android. You can use it to determine if the app is the latest. If not, just custom develop a popup for indication of new app.